# Maximum size of OracleTypes.ARRAY

Tags: java, arrays

Using OracleTypes.ARRAY to pass large amount of data. So building an ARRAY to pass to the database procedure. Is there any maximum size restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to map a `VARRAY` field (the only collections in Oracle are Index-by tables, nested tables and Varrays which act as arrays) the maximum size is 2147483647.